# Skip duplicate row when import excel

Tags: excel, laravel

I want to import some excel data into laravel database. I have successfully completed this but I tried the second time only to import excel update data and skip duplicate row. I am using laravel 6 and mattwebsite 3.1

This is my import class

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Contact;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;


class ContactsImport implements ToModel, WithStartRow
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */

    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Contact([
            'name'        => $row[0],
            'designation' => $row[1],
            'email' => $row[2],
            'phone' => $row[3],
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Imports\ContactsImport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class ExcelController extends Controller
{
    public function importContact()
    {
        Excel::import(new ContactsImport, request()->file('file'));

        return back();
    }
}
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="{{ route('contact.import')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file" class="mb-3">
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Import User Data</button>
</form>
```

Please tell me how I can solve it or give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You might use the [OnEachRow concern](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html):

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Contact;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;

class UsersImport implements OnEachRow
{
    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        $row = $row->toArray();

        $contact = Contact::firstOrCreate(
            ['email' => $row[2]],
            [
                'name' => $row[0],
                'designation' => $row[1],
                'email' => $row[2],
                'phone' => $row[3],
            ]

        );

        if (! $contact->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $contact->update([
                'name' => $row[0],
                'designation' => $row[1],
                'phone' => $row[3],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved it following this way 
    `$data = Excel::toArray(new ContactsImport, request()->file('file'));
     collect(head($data))
    ->each(function ($row) {
    DB::table('contacts')
    ->where('phone', $row['phone'])
    ->updateOrInsert(Arr::except($row, ['id']));
            });`

Comment: Ok, my approach could be a bit cleaner.